# Robocopy - Copy Changed Files to Multiple Locations

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch-file, robocopy

I have used [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) to backup files from my home server for years. It's a simple `/MIR` switch.

However, what I'd like to do is not only update the destination folder, but also copy those same new files to a new folder (with a date time stamp) so I can keep a history of the files that were new and/or changed so I can reference them later if needed.

So basically I want it to backup my files as normal with the /MIR switch (and others for logging, etc). But the same files that are modified and copied over are also copied to another folder with a date stamp time the backup was run (i.e. 'backup-13Jan2010_213027').

My only thought on doing this was to take the log file of folders and files generated and extract the file and folder names and then have it copy those files over. But my skills are lacking to do such a thing.

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this? But I'd prefer to just stick with Robocopy if I can, and can be executed through a command line.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No robocopy idea here, but: FreeFileSync. Or similar. In short: there are other tools, that automatically provide a versioning-function. I guess using such a tool would be way easier. Named tool isn't "pretty" and it took me some time to read the docs and get used to it, but it just does what you want. See here, just as an example: https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=versioning

Comment: Thanks. yeah, I looked at FFS brieflyl before. I was trying to stick with robocopy instead of a third party app, but I am probably asking too much. I guess I'll look into FFS a bit more.

Comment: Comment from [doctorbobapplications](https://superuser.com/users/1453732/doctorbobapplications) (I added this as a comment for him because he doesn't have enough reputation):

Is using xcopy to make a list of files an option, then use xcopy to copy to various locations using that list.

[this should only be a comment but I can't make a comment]

I'm also stuck trying to think how to do it with robocopy. But sometimes it's easier to use something else and add it to a script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if I want to copy files to multiple destinations I make the first copy as sort of a "master copy" (same bus of evene the same HD if possible which gives much better speed). Then I copy the "master copy" to various other locations. It's all done using Robocopy.